# Tessellating SVGs for a page background?

Tags: css, html, svg

I'm trying to tile hexagons in raw SVG by authoring raw svg in a background attribute.  I didn't imagine it would be as hard as it is. The big problem is finding a way to offset the green and blue elements from the left and top without cutting them off.  Or maybe there is.  I tried nesting svg elements in each other so I'd have access to the x and y attributes, but they didn't make life any easier.  I'm very confused.  Sample code is at the bottom, impossible to read because of something about newlines in css files.

Here is the SVG I'm working with.

```
body { 
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
    <svg width="288px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 0 288 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px">
            <polygon style="fill:red;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0px" y="166.28px">
            <polygon style="fill:grey;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
        </svg>
    </svg>'), url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
    <svg width="288px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 0 288 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <svg x="144px" y="-83.14px">
            <polygon style="fill:green;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28"  />
        </svg>
        <svg x="144px" y="83.14px">
            <polygon style="fill:blue;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
        </svg>
    </svg>');
background-repeat: "repeat";
}
```

Here is sample code:

*test.html*

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css"></head><body> Hi</body></html>
```

*test.css:*

```
body { 
color: red;
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="288px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 0 288 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><svg x="0px" y="0px"><polygon style="fill:red;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" /></svg><svg x="0px" y="166.28px"><polygon style="fill:grey;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" /></svg></svg>'), url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="288px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 -83.14 288 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><svg x="144px" y="0"><polygon style="fill:green;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28"  /></svg><svg x="144px" y="166.28px"><polygon style="fill:blue;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" /></svg></svg>');
background-repeat: "repeat";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to resize your svg and keep a blank space so they can overlap

```css
svg {box-shadow:0 0 0 2px;}
```

```html
 <svg width="289px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 0 289 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px">
            <polygon style="fill:red;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0px" y="166.28px">
            <polygon style="fill:grey;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
   </svg>
</svg>


    <svg width="289px" height="332.56px" viewBox="0 0 289 332.56" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <svg x="0px" y="0">
            <polygon style="fill:green;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28"  />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0px" y="166.28px">
            <polygon style="fill:blue;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0px" points="144,166.28 48,166.28 0,83.14 48,0 144,0 192,83.14 144,166.28" />
        </svg>
</svg>
```

and then use background-position:

```css
html {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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), url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) 145px 84px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: background-position! I should have known.  Thank you.